# Flash size on publishing post by Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, publish

I use Facebook Graph API to post on user's wall. I also attach Flash application ("source" parameter) to it.

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'Test name', 
    'message' => 'Custom message', 
    'picture' => 'http://www.example.com/image.png', 
    'link' => 'http://www.example.com', 
    'description' => 'Description of the message', 
    'source' => 'http://www.example.com/flash.swf',
    'access_token' => '... token_here ...',
    'method' => 'post'
);
$ret = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?'.http_build_query($data));
```

The problem that i can't set flash size. For example if use REST API, then you can define attached flash size by "expanded_width" and "expanded_height" parameters.

A few month ago when i tried to publish such post i saw that Facebook set flash size to 398x260, but today when i tried it again, i saw that Facebook set size to 398x224.

1) Does someone know if there is some way to define flash size in Graph API, like in REST API?

2) Is there some official documentation that provide default size of post attachment (source)?